# Convex game implies the Shapley value is in the (non-empty) core. Does the converse hold?

Tags: game-theory

Namely, if the game is non-convex then Shapley value is not in the core?

Answer (score 1):

No, of course not.  The non-convexity might only involve strategies that are so bad nobody would ever want to use them.